# Синхронная обёртка для асинхронного объекта

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть класс Someone, в конструкторе которого есть callback функция, в которую возвращается ошибка или объект:

```
var some = new Someone({...}, (err, data) => {
  ...
});
```

Мне надо придумать как бы сделать некую запускалку для создания такого объекта, которую можно было бы использовать вот так:

```
const some = require('./some');

var someClient = some.createClient({...});
someClient.action();
```

В функции createClient должен создаваться экземпляр класса Someone, а когда экземпляр вернет data, то именно data должна вернуться в someClient. До тех пор, пока не вернется data или ошибка, someClient.action() запускаться не должен - nodejs должна подождать, а не рваться асинхронно запускать нижестоящий код до тех пор пока не отработала обертка.

Как это сделать?

UPD:

Пробую делать обертку так:

```
const Someone = require('./Someone');

function some(config) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      new Someone(config, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
  }).then(data => {
    return data;
  }).catch(err => {
    return err;
  });
}

async function createClient(config) {
  return await some(config);
};

module.exports = {
  createClient: createClient
}
```

В someClient возвращается не data а Promise. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: async and await

Comment: А чем этот вопрос принципиально отличается от предыдущего Вашего вопроса?

Comment: А можно конкретный пример как завернуть callback в промис? Бьюсь над этим уже неделю и ответа как не было так и нет.

Comment: *Что я делаю не так?* Все так, только вместо `var someClient = some.createClient({...});` надо писать `var someClient = await some.createClient({...});`. Ну и этот код должен находится внутри асинхронной же функции. Да, и `.then(...).catch(...)` в функции `some()` не нужно.

Comment: Хорошо, а как тогда мне вынести весь этот синтаксический мусор в обертку, чтобы в коде просто импортировать либу и написать var someClient = some.createClient({...}); и чтобы все работало.

Comment: Никак. Асинхронную функцию нельзя вызвать синхронно.

Comment: А как же тогда это делают в библиотеках для соединения с БД: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#introduction Мне нужна ровно такая же схема: медод для подключения, а потом вызов методов запросов.

Comment: Не смотрел в код библиотеки, но очевидно, `connection.connect()` сохраняет где-то внутри себя промис, и все последующие операции, типа `connection.query()` внутри себя дожидаются его завершения.

Comment: А я вот поискал в репозитории по ключевому слову Promise и его упоминаний там вообще нет. Отсюда вопрос, как можно реализовать механизм ожидания какого-либо действия в nodejs без промисов?

Comment: Через коллбэки. В каком-то смысле промисы - это синтаксический сахар для коллбэков. Любую функцию, использующую коллбэк, можно переделать в промис (см. `util.promisify()`) и наоборот. То есть пожалуйста, если не нравятся промисы, делайте через колбэки. Просто код станет запутаннее.

Comment: если хочешь узнать как работает библиотека - просто посмотри ее исходники, например [метод `connect`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/lib/Connection.js#L67)